# Best practices to get first date and last date of previous month in oracle

Tags: sql, date, time, oracle11g

To get first date (at time 00:00:00) and last date (at time 23:59:59) of previous month I tried below query and it's giving proper output as expected.

Is below way to obtain first date and last date of previous month is
correct and best practices? If not than kindly suggest the best
practices to do the same.

**First Date of previous month(Time Part : 00:00:00) :**

```
 select  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM')  from dual ;
```

**Last Date of previous month (Time Part 23:59:59):**

```
 SELECT last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) + INTERVAL '23:59:59'  HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: For the last day select to_timestamp(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0),'MM')) - interval '1' second from dual; might be neater.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock why the to_timestamp on something that is already a date? Surely `trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '1' second` would be even neater, for the last date of the previous month?

Comment: @Boneist simply so that when the select run in SQL Developer the result is displayed with time.  Without it, it only shows date (at least in my version/settings)

Comment: @JonathanWillcock sounds like you need to change your settings (or possibly your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter) then?

Comment: @Boneist quite probably! :-)

Comment: I am late to this answer, but you need to be aware that 23:59:59 is **not** the last date in the previous month. I ran into this error not long back, the time can be a tenth of a second later. If you are doing a comparison, use "< trunc(sysdate, 'MM')" as this captures all of the fractions of a second for the final hour/minute.

Comment: @BrianLeach the DATE datatype only stores information down to seconds though? Were you using timestamps (which store sub-seconds)? If not, I'd be keen to hear more about your issue, although I second your recommendation regardless.

Answer (score 3):

```
--I got the hard  way
select '01-'||to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'MON-YYYY')Firs_day,
       last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1))Last_day 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2))+1 First_Day, 
       last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) Last_day 
from dual;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM') first_day,last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))+ (1-1/24/60/60) last_day
 from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**